# Fancy TeX (etc.)/Metafont/MetaPost logos?

Tags: feature-request, design

Can we have fancy logos like they have on CTAN, for example on http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm-unicode:

[image]

Comment: How would they be used in posts? A special form of markdown?

Comment: Note: some of us really _don't like_ the use of logos in running text!

Comment: Maybe some capitalization tips for metafont/metapost then?

Answer (score 8):

I strongly hope that we cannot have "fancy logos". I'm on the very same wave as Joseph: Either do the rendering really well, or use a reasonable substitute. Doing it really well is impossible (the rendering in the picture in the question is close to making me vomit, especially `XeTeX`), therefore I certainly prefer substituting by lowercase letters.